# How to set the "ServiceVersion" in WCF client

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a .NET application that is consuming a Java WCF, and I need to change my Reference.cs to set the `ServiceVersion`, I don't know how I can do this.

Someone has some idea?

My SOAP XML should be:

```
   <s:Header>
      <ns:TocHeader>
         <ns:Message>
            <ns:X>
               <ns1:ServiceVersion>12.05</ns1:ServiceVersion>
            </ns:X>
         </ns:Message>
      </ns:TocHeader>
   </s:Header>
```

The XML that .NET is generating:

```
   <s:Header>
      <ns:TocHeader xsi:nil="true"/>
   </s:Header>
```